# How can we publish HTML reports(Generated on Agent machine) in Azure Release Pipeline or Test Plans?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, devops

I am using release pipeline for test case execution. Which generate test reports on Agent machine. I want to publish this HTML report. But i didn't find any extension task which will help me. Any suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by "publish HTML report"? Send it somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to obtain test reporting in Azure Pipeline for both build and release pipeline:

> Supported results formats include CTest, JUnit (including PHPUnit),
>   NUnit 2, NUnit 3, Visual Studio Test (TRX), and xUnit 2.

You could find more detail related info in our official task link: [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Publishing html reports in Azure pipelines is not supported at present. There has been a related user voice:

> Support for generic HTML Publishing inside **Build and Release
>   Pipelines**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/491426/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a.html

Sorry for any inconvenience. Appreciate your understanding. You could vote up and monitor the uservoice. Our PM will kindly review any suggestion there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Html Viewer from Marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakubRumpca.azure-pipelines-html-report&ssr=false#overview

Comment: This is awesome and exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: FYI. At the moment I am able to publish only one report with this plugin -report scrapped from the last task in a step.

Comment: Yes, one report coming from one build. The author has been already informed about this kind of "bug"

Comment: colleague of mine created this thing that supports multiple reports from one build: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShahzebKhan.sap-azure-pipelines-html-report&targetId=61248af4-a8f0-402a-83be-cdce9680dd81&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share a new reporter written by a colleague of mine:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShahzebKhan.sap-azure-pipelines-html-report&ssr=false#overview

Supports multiple tabs